# Anylogic how create new agent and assign properties?

Tags: anylogic, agent

Anylogic: This should be simple but I just cannot find it in the help files..
On creating a new agent instance, we know there are four parameters and what they are, but not in what order they were defined.  Lets say parameters are "type_of_car" (String), "number_of_pax" (Integer), "automatic" (boolean), "fuel_capacity" (double).  Now when calling: `new myagenttype("ford", 5, false, 55)`  the agent gets created as a ford with 55 pax, manual and 5 liter fuel capacity - which is all wrong. (*it seems the definition order of the parameters in the agent definition are in a different order*)

How do we include the parameter name (or definition) when we call `new agenttype()` to avoid this problem, ensuring the right value gets assigned to the right parameter?

The problem originates because of a bug in Anylogic's logic in triggering functions.  We have a Split which creates a new agent and assigns the agent properties on the "On exit copy" - event, however what Anylogic does is it creates the agent, forward it to the next logical block (a decision node), then execute the code of the decision - all wrong now for the agent's properties are undefined - and only then executes the "On exit copy" event which assigns the agent's properties.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not a bug, this is defined in the simulation experiment properties, in the randomness section, with the "selection mode for simultaneous events" property. The default is LIFO, but if you want the opposite behavior in your case you should use FIFO... I always use LIFO too, and in these cases, sometimes I might use a 1milisecond auxiliary delay between the split and the next block in order to control the order manually... if you do that, you will solver your problem in fact... just use a 0.001 miliseconds delay after your split

Now from your Agent Type problem, the arguments for your class constructor should be written in order, and the only way to know the correct order is by using the autocomplete feature when you write new agenttype()... the autocomplete will tell you the order in which you should write your constructor arguments.